# Create child theme with hello-elementor for Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, themes, elementor

I am trying to create a new child theme for a Wordpress website. The parent theme is hello-elementor. I created a folder called hello-elementor-child in the theme folder using SFTP and added the function.php and style.css files into this folder.

Here is what is in the function.php:

```
<?php

/* Function to enqueue stylesheet from parent theme */
function child_enqueue__parent_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_style( ‘parent’, get_template_directory_uri().’/style.css’ );

}

add_action( ‘wp_enqueue_scripts’, ‘child_enqueue__parent_scripts’);
```

Here is what is in the style.css file:

```
/*
Theme Name: Hello Elementor Child
Theme URI:
Description: Hello Elementor Child is a child theme of Hello Elementor, created by Elementor team
Author: Author
Author URI: https://github.com/Drenhat
Template: hello-elementor
Version: 1.0.1
Text Domain: hello-elementor-child
License: GNU General Public License v3 or later.
License URI: https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/
```

I then proceeded to modify some css on in the child theme style.css but nothing is happening on the website. I am not sure what I am missing

If someone could help me understanding what I am missing, it would be greatly appreciated.

I followed the official Hello Elementor [documentation](https://elementor.com/blog/wordpress-child-theme/) and looked at some previous answers for similar problems on Stackoverflow. Nothing seems to work.

Comment: If that's all your code then you're only enqueueing the parent theme's stylesheet. You want to enqueue the child theme's style.css as well, see [Child Themes - Enqueue stylesheet](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet).

Comment: Thank you @cabrerahector. I found a GitHub repo that does all the work for you. The link is here: https://github.com/elementor/hello-theme-child

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative way. I found a [repo](https://github.com/elementor/hello-theme-child) on GitHub. I just downloaded it and uploaded it to the WordPress theme section. This code is working:

```
function hello_elementor_child_enqueue_scripts() {
  wp_enqueue_style(
    'hello-elementor-child-style',
    get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
    [
        'hello-elementor-theme-style',
    ],
    '1.0.0'
  );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hello_elementor_child_enqueue_scripts', 20 );
```